# Python for loops with if statement: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, pandas

I am new to Python and I have been working on this for a few days. I have 9 excel files I am looping over and creating Panda DataFrames.

Each of the 9 xls_file DataFrames have these columns:
  code, date_pub (which is uniform within each xls_file but unique between each xls_file), years_q ...

[xls_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4f4W.jpg)

My other DataFrame is called estimate. This is a single Dataframe with these columns:
  rel, est, date_pub (which is unique)

[estimate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSpNi.jpg)

My goal is to create 4 panda DataFrames named (AR_41, AR_42, DG_44, DG_46)

The DataFrames would look very similar to 'estimate' but would have an additional column named value equal to the last column of a given xls_file with the same date_pub

```
x=0
for x in range(1, 9):
    xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('Data' + str(x) + '.xls')

    final_data = estimate

    for row in estimate:
        for innerrow in xls_file:
            if innerrow['date_pub'] == row['date_pub']:
                final_data['value'].append(row.ix[:,-1])
```

I am getting this error: "string indices must be integers" when checking:

```
if innerrow['date_pub'] == row['date_pub']:
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you mean `append(row.ix[::-1])`?

Comment: AFAIK rows are arrays. Arrays are indexed by integer, not by string. Perhaps ExcelFile has a way to parse the file taking the headers into account, but you are not specifying that, and so what you get are just plain arrays.

Comment: Also you did not show how did you populate `estimate`. Perhaps same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may mean either innerrow or row is actually pointing to a string, when it looks like you need it to be an object. Double-check what your variables are pointing to, you could be over-narrowing the dimension and acessing a string when you want a row or column.

When you call `'string'[i]` in Python, it gets the i-th character in 'string', where i is necessarily an integer. 
For example `s = 'certain_word'` then `print s[2]` will print `'r'`.
This may be what your code is trying to do and I am guessing 'date_pub' is a different variable type.